# Autoit mouseclicks without geting window focus

Tags: focus, autoit

I've got a simple queston about mouse clicks. Is there any way to send a mouseclick without getting window focus? 
For example we got 2 Browsers open. First is Google Chrome and we set a code that will click on random page, while we work on second browser. While code works it will get focus to Google Chrome every time it will click. Is there any way to avoid it? I would like to do stuff on 2nd browser while autoit works with the first one.
Ive tried **ControlClicks** and normal **MouseClicks**, with no luck.
I hope you guys understand my poor english :)

Answer (score 0):

You can focuse back to your other Window right after the click:

```
MouseClick("left", xxx, yyy)
WinActivate("2ND WINDOW")
```

There will be a little delay but not more than 10ms.